# Magento 2 - Save deprecated

Tags: magento2, integration, deprecated

I try to create programmatically an integration in Magento 2.

I follow this tutorial :

https://magecomp.com/blog/create-activate-authorize-a-new-integration-programmatically-in-magento-2/

I have something like that :

```
// Create Integration
$integrationFactory = $this->integrationFactory->create();
$integration = $integrationFactory->setData($integrationData);
$integration->save();
$integrationId = $integration->getId();
$consumerName = 'Integration' . $integrationId;

// Create consumer
$consumer = $this->oauthService->createConsumer(['name' => $consumerName]);
$consumerId = $consumer->getId();
$integration->setConsumerId($consumer->getId());
$integration->save();

// Add grant permission
$this->authorizationService->grantAllPermissions($integrationId);

// Activate and Authorize
$token = $this->tokenFactory->create();
$token->createVerifierToken($consumerId);
$token->setType('access');
$token->save();
```

It's work but all 'save' function are deprecated. I don't succeed to find another way to save integration, consumer and token.

Do anyone have any idea?

Comment: What's the type of $this->tokenFactory? Magento used Service Contracts for saving / loading entities, so you should look for something named TokenRepository instead of using the explicit model.

Comment: You have to use  `Service Contract` (the best way), or `ResourceModel`

Comment: @simonthesorcerer :  $this->tokenFactory type is Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\Token

Comment: @PЯINCƏ Do you have any examples ?

Comment: @Kozame https://www.siphor.com/add-a-magento-2-service-contract/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a Service Contract (maybe depends on the Magento version, they are still in development iirc), so the best way should be using the resource model as pointed out in the comments:

`Magento\Integration\Model\ResourceModel\Oauth\Token->save($myToken)`

Comment: I use Magento\Integration\Model\ResourceModel\Integration and Magento\Integration\Model\ResourceModel\Oauth\Token : work well !